# webOS style view switching on iPhone app

Tags: iphone, interface, core-animation, webos

I have been working with a iPhone app that I would like to have switch views like the Palm Pre does for multitasking. I know the usual way of switching views by using the black bar at the bottom of the app but the app I am working on does not lend itself to having a big black bar in the way (see attached picture #1).

I guess my question is, how do I shrink the current view (Current Location window) and show other views on the sides? (see attached picture #2) Then be able to swipe left and right to view other views. I have no idea how to do this and would be eternally grateful if someone could help me out with this.

http://www.threepixeldrift.com/images/deep-storage/webOScardapp1.jpg
http://www.threepixeldrift.com/images/deep-storage/webOScardapp2.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The architecture should be similar to that of NavigationController: you have a number of ViewControllers each responsible for one card in your app. Then you have a 'super-controller' which controls these ViewControllers, by adding and removing their controlled views from the superview when necessary.

You'll need to use CoreAnimation and write the animations yourself.

Answer (score 0):

i would use a UIScrollView and each card can be a small view that is shown by setting the contentoff set.